# Get files being deleted in windows

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I want to create an application that will save the files being deleted from a flash drive into a part of the flash drive that acts as recycle bin. I want to capture the deletion event of windows so that I can copy the files marked as deleted.

Is there a library that would notify my application if the delete event is being executed?

If using FileSystemWatcher component, I cannot get the files being deleted because it will only notify after the file is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write filesystemfilter or filesystemminifilter driver through Preoperation Callback Routines

as given in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms793697.aspx